# parallel gnu command in conjunction with piping

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, gnu

I am relatively new to informatics, and have just discovered the virtues of the `parallel` command. However, I am having trouble using this in conjunction with piping and output.

I am using this command:

```
parallel -j 2 echo ./hisat2 --dta -p 32 -x path/to/index -U {} | ./samtools view -b - > /path/to/storage/folder/{/.}.bam :::: fs1 > executable.sh
```

`fs1` contains a list of all the files I want to run. `executable.sh` is the executable command list. I wish for each file listed in fs1 to be individually processed by a program (called `hisat2`) and the ouput sam file to be converted into bam format with samtools. However, it does not seem to like the piping - it complains with the following:

```
bash: /path/to/storage/folder/{/.}.bam: No such file or directory
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.
```

How can I overcome this? Is the only way around this to first process all files to sam, and then parallel bam convert?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the pipe and redirection:

```
parallel -j 2 "./hisat2 --dta -p 32 -x path/to/index -U {} | ./samtools view -b - > /path/to/storage/folder/{/.}.bam" :::: fs1
```

Use `--dry-run` to see what would be run:

```
parallel --dry-run -j 2 "./hisat2 --dta -p 32 -x path/to/index -U {} | ./samtools view -b - > /path/to/storage/folder/{/.}.bam" :::: fs1
```

(Are you sure `samtools` is in current dir? Usually that is installed for a wider audience.)

May I suggest you spend an hour walking through `man parallel_tutorial`? Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: this still does not work for me, sorry... should > have a '>'?  I will look at the tutorial, cheers

Comment: No, but try --dry-run.